# Evaluate XPath 2.0 Expression with SAXON S9API

Tags: xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

I am trying to execute an XPath 2.0 expression, I may be missing something, I am able to form the XPathSelector, the question is how to run the selector on a org.w3c.dom.Document Object? My code is below:

```
public class XPath2Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String assemblyXPathString="/child::AssemblyBase/child::Assembly[attribute::roles='ALL' or contains(attribute::roles,$role)]";

    DOMParser parser=new DOMParser();
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("E:\\workspaces\\dev_werewolf\\Platform_Manual\\manual\\UIFramework\\RoleBasedUIAssembly2.xml");
    InputSource inputSource=new InputSource(fis);
    parser.parse(inputSource);
    Document document=parser.getDocument();


    Processor processor=new Processor(false);
    //processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new File("E:\\workspaces\\dev_werewolf\\Platform_Manual\\manual\\UIFramework\\RoleBasedUIAssembly2.xml"));

    XPathCompiler compiler=processor.newXPathCompiler();
    compiler.declareVariable(new QName("role"));

    XPathExecutable executable=compiler.compile(assemblyXPathString);
    XPathSelector selector=executable.load();
    ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("CIO");
    selector.setVariable(new QName("role"),   XdmItem.makeSequence(values));

    //Now what???, how to run the quesry against the 'document'???
    selector.evaluate();//Exception

}//main closing

}//class closing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
selector.setContextItem(item)
```

to set the context node for the XPath evaluation, and the way you get an item that references the root node of a DOM document is to do

```
XdmNode item = processor.newDocumentBuilder().wrap(document);
```

Note that you should only use DOM nodes with Saxon if you have a very good reason; using Saxon's internal tree implementation is often 5 to 10 times faster. If you don't care what kind of tree it is, use

```
XdmNode item = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(
  new File("E:\\workspaces\\dev_werewolf\\Platform_Manual\\manual\\UIFramework\\RoleBasedUIAssembly2.xml"));
```